# Linker error encountered upon attempting to use RtlInitUnicodeString()

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ntdll

The function `RtlInitUnicodeString()` used to initialize the `UNICODE_STRING` structure cannot be used as a linker error stating that an `unresolved external symbol RtlInitUnicodeString referenced in function ***func_name*** (LNK2019)` is thrown during compilation.

I tried using the statement `#pragma comment(lib, "NtosKrnl.lib")` to solve the issue at hand (as I assumed that linking the library mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlinitunicodestring#requirements) would resolve it) but a linker error stating the message `cannot open file 'ntoskrnl.lib' (LNK1104)` is thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're writing a normal Windows program you don't have access to kernel routines. ntoskrnl.lib isn't used in user mode programming.

Comment: user mode apps can use `RtlInitUnicodeString()` and related functions from `ntdll.dll` instead.

Comment: you need use *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib*

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? Could please share the solution as answer and [accept](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function cannot be called directly as they belong to the internal API and their mere prototype header is exposed via the `winternl.h` header file (at least in this case). In order to use the functions that are part of the internal API, one can either use run-time dynamic linking to link the `Ntdll.dll` library as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/calling-internal-apis?redirectedfrom=MSDN) or link the library file `ntdll.lib`, which is a provided as a part of the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).